# How to load a JavaScript file using thymeleaf + springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have 2 methods that return a `ModelAndView` Object.

The first one gets the mapping from the browser and returns a `modelandview` that links to to an `html` file.

On that html file on the end I link a script tag to a spring root like this:

```
<!-- Calendar Js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../static/assets/vendor/netcorr/calendar/calendar.js"
        th:src="@{/customer/web/wall/calendarItems(wallId=${wallId})}"></script>
```

In the controller,  I have the second method that loads based on this call that I'm making  just above:

```
/customer/web/wall/calendarItems(wallId=${wallId})
```

This method throws into the `modelandview`  some objects that i need in the view.

This `modelandview` has root to a `js` file.

The problem is that the `html` does not load the `js` file that is called above.

Tried some solutions found on Stackoverflow, the solutions were to handle all of this in the `mvdconfig` controller.

And go throw the dependencies and make sure the dependencies are for Spring 4.

I m using Spring 1.5.9 and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

```
@GetMapping(value = "/customer/web/wall/calendar", params = {"wallId"})
    public ModelAndView calendar(@RequestParam(value = "wallId") long wallId,
                                 Authentication auth,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/customer/wall/calendar");
        modelAndView.addObject("wallId",wallId);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/customer/web/wall/calendarItems", params = {"wallId"})
    public ModelAndView calendarItems(@RequestParam(value = "wallId") long wallId,
                                 Authentication auth,
                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        User currentUser = (User) auth.getPrincipal();

        Set<Long> wallIds = new HashSet<>();
        wallIds.add(wallId);
        PlaybookFilters playbookFilters = new PlaybookFilters();
        playbookFilters.setCustomerId(currentUser.getCustomerId());
        playbookFilters.setWallIds(wallIds);

        List<Playbook> playbooks = playbookService.getPlaybooks(playbookFilters);

        Date dateBegin = calendarService.getDateBegin();
        Date dateEnd = calendarService.getDateEnd();

        List<CalendarItem> calendarItems = calendarService.fetchPbiForPlaybooks(playbooks, dateBegin, dateEnd);

        ArrayNode items = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        calendarItems.forEach(item -> items.add(item.toJsonNode()));

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/customer/wall/calendarItems");
        modelAndView.addObject("events", items);
        return modelAndView;

    }
```

Comment: Try this tag

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../static/assets/vendor/netcorr/calendar/calendar.js"
        th:src="@{${'/customer/web/wall/calendarItems' + wallId}}"></script>`

Comment: Also what would help if you could show us the HTML output and what output you are expecting.